# Dell SC1425 Server Fan Issue

Tags: fan, dell-poweredge

I have the above server in my garage and use it for web development. For the last couple of weeks the fans have been running at full speed and looks like one of them has failed as I ran a diagnostics tool that told me BMC 5A was reading 0 rpm.

Can anyone tell me how I can identify which fan is 5A once I open up the server?

Is it an easy job to change the fan? I have not changed a fan on a server before so any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the [manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-1425sc_User%27s%20Guide2_en-us.pdf) is your friend here. It suggests all the fans are on the same header and you can trace the fan from there. I'd personally suggest booting up the system up and checking visually which fan isn't turning.

Here's the diagram with the appropriate header circled

[image]

This [review of that server](http://halisway.blogspot.sg/2005/09/dell-poweredge-sc1425-review.html) has a bunch of pictures, should you want to see the gory innards of your server prior to performing surgery yourself. Replacing the fans themselves wouldn't be hard, but those don't look like consumer grade, regular fans to me. If you're looking for a replacement they are [dell FC 7007](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=Dell%20PN%20F7007&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs&gws_rd=cr&ei=UKehUuPhL8XXrQet6oBA) fans.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That's really helpful and yes I have ordered the correct fan off eBay and will be giving this a go as soon as possible because at the moment it sounds like a 747 taking off! One other thing I'd like to ask you if that's ok - the diagnostics tool states there are 9 fans however I can only see 2 banks of 4 fans. It states that there is Fan 1, Fan 2A & 2B, Fan 3A & 3B, Fan 4A & 4B, Fan 5A & 5B.

Comment: Fans 2-5 are actually 2 fan units in a push-pull configuration so fan '5' is fan '5A' and '5B'

Comment: Oh, and if you haven't already http://serverfault.com/questions/412213/dell-poweredge-sc1425-fan-control and http://serverfault.com/questions/370172/disable-fan-management-on-dell-poweredge-sc1425 are worth reading. In addition, someone mentioned the heat sink compound crumbling, so it may be worth checking and replacing if needed while you're mucking about the system.